# How do I align the circuit junctions with the op-amp inputs? (and be smaller)

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Simple drawing... but I can't figure out how to align the circuit junctions with the op-amp inputs, unless I fudge it by adjusting manually. Is there a way to do so automatically? (and make the junction dots smaller?)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american, font=\sffamily]  
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/height=0.1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width=0.3333}

\node[nigbt](qcl) at (0,2.5) {};
\node[op amp, yscale=-1](u1) at (2,0.75) {};
\draw
(0,0) to [R=$R_s$](0,1.5) to (qcl.E)
(u1.-) to [short, -*]  (0,0.3)
(u1.+) to [short, -*] (0,1.2)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aha, figured out another way, by not trying to use the `-*` syntax and manually making circles aligned using `-|`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american, font=\sffamily]  
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/height=0.1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width=0.3333}

\node[nigbt](qcl) at (0,2.5) {};
\node[op amp, yscale=-1](u1) at (2,0.75) {};
\draw
(0,0) to [R=$R_s$](0,1.5) to (qcl.E)
(u1.-) -|  (0,0.3)
(u1.+) -|  (0,1.2)
;
\fill (u1.- -| 0,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\fill (u1.+ -| 0,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one way to draw perpendicular lines.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american, font=\sffamily]  
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/height=0.1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width=0.3333}

\node[nigbt](qcl) at (0,2.5) {};
\node[op amp, yscale=-1](u1) at (2,0.75) {};
\draw
(0,0) to [R=$R_s$,n=R1] (0,1.5) -- (qcl.E)
(u1.-) to [short, -*] (u1.- -| R1)
(u1.+) -- (u1.+ -| R1) node[circ]{}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```